# Where should I put image meta data and license information?

Tags: google-search, images, licenses, png, creative-commons

I have a PNG picture in a web page. The page has a CC-BY button and links (with a `rel="license"` attribute, as the CC license picker generates) at the bottom, it has a title, and some more descriptive text.

Is that enough to e.g., have Google list the image (or page) with its CC-BY license when someone does an image search for images "Labeled for noncommercial reuse with modification"?

Or, asking differently, what meta data should that PNG file have? Title? I've looked at the [ExifTool PNG tags list](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-ExifTool/lib/Image/ExifTool/TagNames.pod#PNG_TextualData_Tags) but I don't know what tags search engines look at. In particular, that tag list does not even include a License tag --- would I use Copyright instead?